# Retrofit 2: Catch connection timeout exception

Tags: android, retrofit, connection-timeout, okhttp

I have the following setup:

```
final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(ROOT)
        .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
        .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);
```

I am trying to handle the situation in which my server is down and the user gets a connection timeout exception, this is my logging:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.53 (port 3000) after 5000ms
```

Full logging: http://pastebin.com/gscCGb7x

Is there a way to route this into the retrofit failure method so I can handle it over there?

Comment: In my app, I do get SocketTimeoutExceptions passed to my failure method wrapped in RetrofitExceptions. Are you sure that you're not getting them there? They may also be logged elsewhere, but they should be passed to failure().

Comment: Hmm very weird, I did some debugging and now it does work :S.

Comment: Hi jdruwe, could you manage to catch the connection exception? I too want to do the same. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56301801/7254873

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**For Retrofit 2**

Define a listener in your web service instance:

```
public interface OnConnectionTimeoutListener {
    void onConnectionTimeout();
}
```

Add an interceptor to your web service:

```
public WebServiceClient() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.setConnectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.setReadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            return onOnIntercept(chain);
        }
    });
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();
    webService = retrofit.create(WebService.class);
}
```

Enclose your intercep code with try-catch block and notify listener when exception happens:

```
private Response onOnIntercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    try {
        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        String content = UtilityMethods.convertResponseToString(response);
        Log.d(TAG, lastCalledMethodName + " - " + content);
        return response.newBuilder().body(ResponseBody.create(response.body().contentType(), content)).build();
    }
    catch (SocketTimeoutException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        if(listener != null)
            listener.onConnectionTimeout();
    }

    return chain.proceed(chain.request());
}
```

Comment: This interceptor is great, but whe TimeoutException occurs in my subscriber's onError(Throwable t) i get this: t.getMessage() = "network interceptor com.test.presentation.application.di.AppRestModule$2@2320fd48 must call proceed() exactly once". Is that OK? Or maybe we should not call proceed second time?

Comment: @Olcay Ertaş - Great answer! Curious on how you get/set lastCalledMethodName for your logging, would you mind sharing?

Comment: @Codeversed, my web service methods assigns this value. There is no concurrency for this methods so it doesn't cause any problem. But i guess adding method name to request would be better for concurrent requests.

Comment: I think its changed with `httpClient.connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
httpClient.readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: @OlcayErtaş chain.proceed(chain.request()) will be called two times! Is it ok?

Comment: Where does `UtilityMethods.convertResponseToString(response);` come from?

Comment: It is my implementation.

Comment: @OlcayErtaş Does this solve anything? What you catch here is already thrown. When I get this exception, the app crashes because it is raised in OkHttp: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3320

Comment: Yes it does. Did you try my soulition or are just asking before trying it?

Comment: UtilityMethods.convertResponseToString(response)  - what does this exactly do?

Comment: Alberto, it does exactly what it says, converts Response object to String.

Comment: why not just check the throwable instance to see if it is a SocketTimeoutException in the failure route?

Comment: Thanks! @rpm, it is `response.body().string()` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37118725/2914140).

Comment: @hjchin, if you use RxJava or Kotlin coroutines, there is no `onFailure` branch. So, you can try it only in callbacks.

Comment: This answer fails. `return chain.proceed(chain.request());` returns `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`. Also the author doesn't check `UnknownHostException`.

Comment: This method is to catch `SocketTimeoutException` not `UnknownHostException`.

Comment: @OlcayErtaş, agree. I saw many topics with interceptors. They all rethrow exceptions to upper level, so we have to catch them in callbacks, try-catch or RxJava. Your answer is good. We can catch different Network exceptions, not only timeout. Also thanks for getting JSON in `content` variable. Here I can change it without writing a Gson deserializer.

Comment: response.newBuilder().body(ResponseBody.create(response.body().contentType(), content)).build(); 
why this line? , we do not change anything ?

Comment: ok good the catch recevie the excetion but last line     return chain.proceed(chain.request()); throw exception

Comment: @OlcayErtaş check my last comment plz

Comment: @asa it has been very long time since I have last used Retrofit and do any coding on Android. I can't remember why I have used it.

Comment: @asa please check this: https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/

Comment: @asa I am developing native iOS applications for last 4 years.

Answer (score 54):

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
    if(t instanceof SocketTimeoutException){
        message = "Socket Time out. Please try again.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please let me know what about to handle the connectivity exception?

Comment: for me throwable instanceof UnknownHostException   work!

Comment: So you say that in onResponse there is no chanse to have timeout?

Comment: @Kenji from my tests, it seems to always go to onFailure

Answer (score 18):

In case someone come here with **Kotlin/Coroutines** facing the same issue, add an error handler to your coroutines scope:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch(handler) {
```

while the handler by itself looks like:

```
val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
    Log.t("Network", "Caught $exception")
}
```

Comment: Yup this is correct for Kotlin coroutines. Even if you put your whole code within a try catch it will not catch the exception if you have used a coroutine. In that case this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 6):

None of the answers quite worked for me but they led me in the right direction. See below how I did it in Kotlin.

You can either throw the exceptions in the `ErrorInterceptor` and catch them in your api call function:

```kotlin
class ErrorInterceptor : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Chain): Response {

        val request = chain.request()

        try {
            val response = chain.proceed(request)
            val bodyString = response.body!!.string()

            return response.newBuilder()
                .body(bodyString.toResponseBody(response.body?.contentType()))
                .build()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            when (e) {
                is SocketTimeoutException -> {
                    throw SocketTimeoutException()
                }

               // Add additional errors... //

            }
        }
    }
```

Or bundle exceptions with a response object; something like this:

```kotlin
class ErrorInterceptor : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Chain): Response {

        val request = chain.request()

        try {
            val response = chain.proceed(request)
            val bodyString = response.body!!.string()

            return response.newBuilder()
                .body(bodyString.toResponseBody(response.body?.contentType()))
                .build()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            var msg = ""
            val interceptorCode: Int

            when (e) {
                is SocketTimeoutException -> {

                    msg = "Socket timeout error"
                    interceptorCode = 408

                }

               // Add additional errors... //

            }

             return Response.Builder()
                .request(request)
                .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
                .code(interceptorCode)
                .message(msg)
                .body("{${e}}".toResponseBody(null)).build()
        }
    }
}
```

Add the `ErrorInterceptor` to your `okHttpClient`:

```kotlin
okHttpClient.newBuilder()
                .addInterceptor(ErrorInterceptor())
                .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                 // ... //
                .build()
```

And then something like this in your repository layer:

```kotlin
suspend fun makeAPIRequest(): Resource<ApiResponse> {

        return withContext(ioDispatcher) {

            var response: Response<ApiResponse>? = null

            try {
                response = getResponse()

                // Do additional ops on response here //

            } catch (e: Exception) {

                // Exceptions thrown in ErrorInterceptor will propagate here

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: hey, is this working for you full-proof?. I tried it but still, 50% of the time exception is skipped by the interceptor and not caught in case of multiple async API calls.

Comment: @Arpit J. is the interceptor even processing the chain when it does not catch errors? I haven't used this error interceptor for multiple async calls but I would start investigating there. If it does not process the chain, then it's something that has to do with how OkHttp interceptors work, otherwise it has something to do with my implementation. If you manage to solve you issue, I'd be curious to know what was wrong and how you fixed it. Thanks and good luck!

Comment: Sorry but I'm swamped already. If this is an interceptor issue, I don't have any clue how to fix. You should look into something like this: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3714

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the exception does get wrapped into a RetrofitException so you can handle it in the failure method.

Comment: I am using Retrofit 2.2. May I know how can I catch the RetrofitException ? I have an interceptor surrounded by try catch so I am getting SocketTimeoutException handled. But problem is how to let my CallBack know that this particular error is because of the connection timeout ?

Comment: @cgr please llok at my answer.

Comment: @Oclay, thansk for the response. I finally did that way. Thanks ! ;)

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit more complicated. With Retrofit you can make API calls that are either synchronous or asynchronous.

If your endpoint returns void and has a callback it is asynchronous.
If it returns something and has no callback it's synchronous.

For asynchronous calls you get this exception in the `onFailure(...)` method of your callback.

For synchronous calls you don't get it at all, unless you wrap your call in a try/catch.

```
try {
   // your synchronous call goes here  
} catch (RetrofitError error) {
   // handle errors
}
```

*Update: The above answer applies to Retrofit 1.9. Retrofit 2.0 has changed this a lot. If you're wondering about how things now work in Retrofit 2.0, this article gives some pointers http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en*

Comment: In Retrofit 2.0, there is no `RetrofitError`.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer saying it applies to 1.9 and added a link to an article on how 2.0 works

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this for two reasons:

1. I personnaly tried increasing connection timeout but, evetually, it doesn't really solve the problem at its root. Besides, user is not supposed to wait for longer than 10 seconds according to [this post](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/website-response-times/).
2. In a real world application, we would rather do our best to implement a solution in as clean as possible way.

So, here's a solution that I came up with in **Kotlin**. It's inspired from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34091088/4590265) provided by [@Olcay Ertaş](https://stackoverflow.com/users/614065/olcay-erta%C5%9F) and combined with [Google's recommended architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide) for Android apps.

1. Create a `TimeoutInterceptor` interface:

   ```
    interface TimeoutInterceptor : Interceptor
   ```
2. Implement the `TimeoutInterceptor` interface:

   ```
    class TimeoutInterceptorImpl : TimeoutInterceptor {

        override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
            if (isConnectionTimedOut(chain))
                throw SocketTimeoutException()
            return chain.proceed(chain.request())
        }

        private fun isConnectionTimedOut(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Boolean {
            try {
                val response = chain.proceed(chain.request())
                val content = response.toString()
                response.close()
                Log.d(tag, "isConnectionTimedOut() => $content")
            } catch (e: SocketTimeoutException) {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
    }
   ```
3. In your `ApiService` interface, add the `TimeoutInterceptor` to the `OkHttpClient` builder:

   ```
    val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
            // Add timeout interceptor
            .addInterceptor(timeoutInterceptor)
            // Set a 5s custom connect timout
            .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
   ```

As you might have noticed, you can set a custom connect timeout. Otherwise, it's left to 10 seconds as a default value according to the [documentation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/-builder/connect-timeout/).

4. Create an enum class `ConnectionState`. It will provide an enum constant object `CONNECTION_TIMEOUT` which will be used further to convey the appropriate connection (or API call) state from `EntityNetworkDataSource` class to the View class (if you follow [Google's MVVM pattern](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide#overview)):

   ```
    enum class ConnectionState {
        CONNECTED, NOT_CONNECTED, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT
    }
   ```
5. Assuming your `EntityNetworkDataSource` interface would look something like this:

   ```
    interface EntityNetworkDataSource {
        val fetchedEntity: LiveData<Entity>

        // Wrap your ConnectionState object in LiveData in order to be able to observe it in the View
        val connectionState: LiveData<ConnectionState>

        // Fetch `Entity` object from the network
        suspend fun fetchEntity(id: Int)
    }
   ```
6. In the `EntityNetworkDataSource` implementation class, you can properly catch the `SocketTimeoutException` as shown below, inside the `fetchEntity(id: Int)` implementation:

   ```
    class EntityNetworkDataSourceImpl(
            private val apiService: ApiService
    ) : EntityNetworkDataSource {

        private val _fetchedEntity = MutableLiveData<Entity>()

        override val fetchedEntity: LiveData<Entity>
            get() = _fetchedEntity

        // We want to keep our MutableLiveData private because they can be changed.
        // So we want to be able to update them only from the inside of this class
        private val _connectionState = MutableLiveData<ConnectionState>()

        override val connectionState: LiveData<ConnectionState>
            get() = _connectionState

        override suspend fun fetchEntity(id: Int) {
            try {
                val fetchedEntity = apiService
                        .getEntity(id)
                        .await()

                // Convey the updated connection state to the observer View
                _connectionState.postValue(ConnectionState.CONNECTED)

                _fetchedEntity.postValue(fetchedEntity)
            } catch (e: SocketTimeoutException) {
                Log.e(tag, "Connection timeout. ", e)
                // Catch the SocketTimeoutException and post the updated connection state to the observer View
                _connectionState.postValue(ConnectionState.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
            }
        }
    }
   ```

The same principle applies to any connection exception you wana intercept and catch.

Comment: Tons of code and the only important part is the try..catch in fetchEntity()... :(