# Refreshable calls with retrofit with sleep time

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm working on a project using `Retrofit` to make calls in an API, however I need to make one of the calls **refreshable** depending on the timeout returned by the API while displaying an `AlertDialog` on the screen. What are the ways forward on this topic?

Comment: You may use  [Observable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observable.html) class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I hope this would help as alternative solution**

I had similar problem once. I ended up with requesting the API from `AlertDialog`and 
upon successful response displayed it on `AlertDialog` 
else 
displayed the Retry `Button` that would resend the request (when request timeout or similar issues)

Comment: Retry `Button` is not solution for me. The Retry must be automatic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921667/retrofit-and-okhttpclient-catch-connection-timeout-in-failure-method

Comment: Not yet. It is not connection timeout, the API responds fast with code 200. I who need  a while to redo the call.

Comment: @rodrigomedeiros Please add more details

Comment: Ok @Amit Bhandari, i'm sorry. I call an API which should return me a PDF, however, it might happen that it's still being prepared. In that case, it returns me a parameter with time who i'm need wait for redo the call. My problem is to wait this time with an `AlertDialog` and call the API again.

Comment: If the the response land at onSuccess() if the response contains remaining time, show progress at dialog and start the thread at onSuccess which will resend the request after the remaining time.

Comment: Thread.sleep inside in onSuccess() is a best practice for retry call? It seems weird. =/

Comment: timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Your database code here
  }
}, timeToResendRequestInMilliSecond);

Comment: Resolved. But I believe there are more elegant solutions to do that. Thank you!

Comment: @rodrigomedeiros  I believe custom callback  would do the same job but at the end it will run the same code                                                 https://gist.github.com/facundomr/2362c57383368e9fd6cf