# Retrofit, TimeoutException

Tags: java, android, retrofit, timeoutexception

I'm using retrofit authentication, and I have a timeoutexception. I saw many questions, but I can't solve this.

Here's the code

```
public class FragmentRegistration extends Fragment {
View mainView;

EditText username, email, password, name;
Button button;

ApiClient pentairAPIClient = ApiClient.getInstance();

SupportopObj supportopObj = new SupportopObj();
SupportopObjActivate supportopObjActivate = new SupportopObjActivate();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainView = inflater.inflate
            (R.layout.registration, container, false);

    username = mainView.findViewById(R.id.username);
    email = mainView.findViewById(R.id.email);
    password = mainView.findViewById(R.id.password);
    name = mainView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    button = mainView.findViewById(R.id.register);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //String s = name.getText().toString();
            //String split[] = s.split(" ");

            supportopObj.setFirstName("Tester");
            supportopObj.setLastName("Testryan");
            supportopObj.setUsername(username.getText().toString());
            supportopObj.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
            supportopObj.setPassword(password.getText().toString());

            supportopObjActivate.setUsername(supportopObj.getUsername());
            supportopObjActivate.setEmail(supportopObj.getEmail());
            supportopObjActivate.setPassword(supportopObj.getPassword());
            supportopObjActivate.setType("generic");
            updateApp();               
        }
    });

    return mainView;
}


public void updateApp() {

    Call<ResponseBody> call = pentairAPIClient.registration(supportopObj);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                activationCall();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something went wrong",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}


public void activationCall() {
    Call<ResponseBody> callActive = pentairAPIClient.activation(supportopObjActivate);
    callActive.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                try {
                    String data = response.body().string();
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data);
                    String client_id = obj.getString("client_id");
                    String client_secret = obj.getString("client_secret");

                    tokenCall(client_id, client_secret);

                } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error in activation",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}


public void tokenCall(String client_id, String client_secret) {
    Call<ResponseBody> token = pentairAPIClient.get_token("password", client_id, client_secret,
            supportopObj.getEmail(), supportopObj.getPassword());

    token.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(response.body()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something wrong.....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You're on failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

I have no error in retrofit, I'm doing debugging and I see all the process, so I getting client id and secret successfully, then I'm getting a timeoutexception in the last onfailure(),

```
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) 
{
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You're onfailure",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

watch the code, that's the last line. How to fix it? The app not crashes, but in debug he drops timeoutexception like this.                                            `t={SocketTimeoutException@830038722120}java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout` . In OkHttpClient the

```
readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  all are 10, i tried to set it 100, not helps. Help me. Thanks.
```

Comment: You did set the timeout for 10 seconds, check the response in the Postman or any other software you use to check the time execution and change the timeout accordingly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380844/how-to-set-timeout-in-retrofit-library

Comment: have you refer ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921667/retrofit-and-okhttpclient-catch-connection-timeout-in-failure-method

Comment: Man don't send this questions i already saw them, they don't help me. In postman the time is 400-900ms.