# How to fix SSL handshake timed out in Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

In my application I want get data from server and show this into `RecyclerView`.
For get data from server I use **Retrofit2** and I write below codes.
But when running application after some time show me `E/priceResLog: Err : SSL handshake timed out` in `onFailure` from **Retrofit2**!

**My codes :**

```
public class ApiUtilsPrice {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://core.arzws.com/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**Activity codes :**

```
private void getCoinData() {
    loaderLayout(true);
    Call<GoldListResponse> call = apiInterface.getGoldPrice();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<GoldListResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<GoldListResponse> call, Response<GoldListResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    loaderLayout(false);
                    model.clear();
                    model.addAll(response.body().getGoldBoard());
                    coinAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    isSendApi = true;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<GoldListResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("priceResLog", "Err : " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

How can I fix it? please help me thanks.

Comment: increase timeout 60 to 90.

Comment: @HemantParmar, why?

Comment: issue with server. chain your certificate properly.no need to change in android side.

Comment: You need to add default certificate to retrofit

Comment: don't add static certificates.

Comment: @ManishNegi, can you send to me code how can I it? because I am amateur and really need your help

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel, how can we fix it from server? can you help me?  because I am amateur and really need help you.

Comment: @WoW.j have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34091088/5110595)

Comment: is the issue fixed?

Answer (score 8):

Add the following piece of code

```
public Retrofit getRetrofit(Gson gson) {
            return new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(ZoneApplication.getContext().getString(R.string.feed_data_base_url))
                    .client(HttpClientService.getUnsafeOkHttpClient())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(new NullOnEmptyConverterFactory())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();

        }
```

or change your code to

```
public static Retrofit getClient() {

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .client(HttpClientService.getUnsafeOkHttpClient())
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

Create another class called HttpClientService and add the following code

```
public class HttpClientService {
    public static OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {

        try {
            final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        @SuppressLint("TrustAllX509TrustManager")
                        @Override
                        public void checkClientTrusted(
                                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain,
                                String authType) {
                            //Do nothing
                        }

                        @SuppressLint("TrustAllX509TrustManager")
                        @Override
                        public void checkServerTrusted(
                                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain,
                                String authType) {
                            //Do nothing
                        }

                        @Override
                        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[0];
                        }
                    }};
            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts,
                    new java.security.SecureRandom());

            final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext
                    .getSocketFactory();

            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
                    .hostnameVerifier(org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER)
                    .build();
            return okHttpClient;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you send to me your Skype ID? please

Comment: I do not understand, what is use of creating okHttpClient instance, if we are passing HttpClientService.getUnsafeOkHttpClient() as a client?

Comment: It has really fixed the https connection on old android. Thank you!

Comment: @deprecated [SSLSocketFactory], is any alternate syntax?